# upload data to S3 through custom RESTful API

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

My app need to do 2 things:

1. upload customer's data to my S3
2. save customer's information to my databsae, and trigger some function.

Currently I'm implementing it using a standard RESTful API (.NET core 3.1) as below image, my RESTfull API app hosted on an EC2 with 4 core, 8GB RAM, 100GB Disk.

**The problem is when user push a big file in the attachment (several GB) or multiple user upload multiple files at same time, the API will be hanged, and my app halted.**

I've searched and tried with Amazone API Gateway but it just a way for user with FRONT END to separate data to 2 destination, in my case, my users consume my RESTful API directly without any front end.

Is there any way to upload file to S3 through RESTful API without overloaded my EC2?

[image: my workflow]

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload gigabytes of data through API gateway, as it has [hard limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table) of **10 MB**. Generally you would have to re-architect your application to upload directly to S3 such big files. This is usually achieved by means of [S3 pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

In such a solution, your API would be only used to get the **S3 pre-signed** url from the backend, and then your users or your app would upload the big files using HTTP PUT to the url.